# How to convert UTC time to local unix time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a React app with a survey component. If user clicks on skip survey button then after n-days (or hours) the survey should appear again. The rejected time is in UTC format comes from backend when app is loading.

I'd like to make a function which compares a rejected date in UTC and a locale date (users can be from anywhere around the world) and if it returns true then render the survey component.

The problem is with converting UTC date to unix (millisecond?) to compare it with locale date. How can I do it?

```
const shouldShowSurvey = (rejectedDateUTC, repeatIntervalMs) => {
  // rejectedDateMs is a UTC unix time
  const rejectedDateMs = new Date(rejectedDateUTC).getTime();
  const now = new Date().getTime();

  return rejectedDateMs + repeatIntervalMs < now;
};

shouldShowSurvey("2023-05-03T13:02:08.107402", 5000);
```

Comment: `new Date("2023-05-03T13:02:08.107402")` will always be parsed as a local time. To ensure the date is parsed in any specific timezone you will need to include some sort of timezone info in the date string - for UTC you should use `Z` i.e. `"2023-05-03T13:02:08.107402Z"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `Z` as a suffix of the ISOString of UTC Date for belonging the right UTC format.

```js
const shouldShowSurvey = (rejectedDateUTC, repeatIntervalMs) => {
  // rejectedDateMs is a UTC unix time
  const rejectedDateMs = new Date(rejectedDateUTC+'Z').getTime();
  const now = new Date().getTime();
  return rejectedDateMs + repeatIntervalMs < now;
};

console.log(shouldShowSurvey("2023-05-03T13:02:08.107402", 5000));
```

Credit to [phuzi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76164427/how-to-convert-utc-time-to-local-unix-time/76164619#comment134317783_76164427).

Answer (score 1):

You possibly misunderstand how Javascript Date objects work.

The Date object is essentially a wrapper with some affordances around a millisecond UTC integer timestamp, which is what `Date.prototype.getTime` returns to you. ***Always***.

There's no such thing as a "local date" vs. a "utc date", they are *all* UTC dates but some of those convenience methods (e.g. `toString`, `toLocaleString`) will return a *string representation* of that UTC date converted to user's local timezone, because local/string representations are what *users* care about, not *programmers*.

The only difference (and the problem you're having) is going the *other* way: i.e. from string representation to Date object. If you, the programmer, do not supply a timezone with a string it will have to guess, and depending on the format of the string it will sometimes be interpreted as a string of a local time (e.g. `new Date('2023-05-02T00:00:00');`) and sometimes be interpreted as a string of a UTC (e.g. `new Date('2023-05-02');`).

You can either memorize all the obscure and possibly implementation-defined rules around datestring parsing... or you can provide an explicit timezone when parsing from a string and then the resulting Date object will be unambiguously correct. Once you've parsed it correctly all the standard mathematical comparisons (like `>` and `<`) will work on the Date objects.